# MPAndroidChart XAxisLabels round

Tags: mpandroidchart

I have line chart with X axis is distance(milage).
I add entry with index which correspond to distance in meters (1 , 123, 10145 etc.).
Is any possibility to automaticly scale X labels to round indexes (10, 1000 ,1km, 10km etc.) ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Create a custom formatter like:

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // use one decimal
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        // write your logic here
        return mFormat.format(value) + " $"; // e.g. append a dollar-sign
    }
}
```

And set that formattor to the `DataSet` object like:

```
lineDataSet.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
```

> Like this, you can make your own formattor class and set it to
>   `DataSet`.

You can refer [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface) link for more details.

Comment: This method for formatting of already automatically selected labels.
I would like that only labels corresponding to integers were automatically drawed.
At big zoom  - meters, at moderate zoom - hundreds of meters, then kilometers, etc.